# Android camera video mirror

Tags: android, video, camera, mirror

Hello android developers,

I am using camera API, and facing a problem which cause the front camera video flip mirror when finish record and display on videoView.

So is there a solution to scale the Camera/VideoView mirroring?

If the problem was in picture I could use matrix scale on the image.

Thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: Is your capturing image working fine?

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about video, and the video working fine, just with mirror.

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/yousufshawon/CustomCameraApp
This is for only camera . For video recording use " mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(imageRotation);"  before "mMediaRecorder.prepare();"

Comment: I am using "mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(imageRotation);" but this is not the problem. The problem is the scaling, in camera picture you can use "matrix.setScale()". thanks for your answer but In my case I am using video.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `MediaRecorder` because it's not an orientation problem, it's about frames that you have to mirroir yourself to achieve this result.

The optimal solution is to use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) which is one of the best tool to do the video morroring with command line. With this tool you can still record with `MediaRecorder` and use ffmpeg command after recording to reverse frames but if your video is too large it can be long to treat and therefore does not meet the need.

Another way would be using OpenCV with ffmpeg to get the mirorred video at the end of the recording.